# Netbeans 7.1.2 JavaFX UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, java-7

I've just upgraded my Netbeans to 7.1.2 as I thought I'd have a bash at some JavaFX development, however I'm not having a lot of fun.

First I downloaded the newest Netbeans and installed it, all fine.

Then Netbeans told me I didn't have JavaFX support, so I downloaded the jdk-7 from Oracle and the netbeans JavaFX plugin, and now I can create JavaFX applications.

However, whenever I try to compile a JavaFX app, I get the following error:

```
Error: failed to msvcr100.dll java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\JavaFX 2.1 Runtime\bin\msvcr100.dll: Can't find dependent libraries

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\JavaFX 2.1 Runtime\bin\glass.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

Now both of these mentioned files exist, and they are in the locations mentioned, I'm assuming the problem is something to do with my classpath and/or the Sun/Oracle Netbeans previous installation I had.

I can't really be bothered to uninstall/reinstall all of my Java stuff, so I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions on how to fix this?

Some articles I've read have mentioned copying certain DLLs directly into the project workspace, but that doesn't sound right to me.

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: The errors indicate you don't have some libraries those .dlls depend on.  You will either need to make sure your library path includes the directory where those dependent files reside (if you have them at some external folder), or copy them to the project folder so the loader can find them.  The latter approach is easier from a distribution point of view

Comment: Thanks Attila.  

I understand this, but these errors are coming from newly created JavaFX apps.  I haven't done any development on them, simply created a new JavaFX application and tried to run it, so I don't know what dependencies are missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click your Netbeans project and click to "Properties". Navigate to "Libraries" and determine which "Java Platform" is used by the current project (which is selected one in the dropdown list). Click the "Manage Platforms..." nearby and select the determined Java platform. Go to JavaFX tab then check if the JavaFX is enabled and points to the correct SDK and Runtime paths in your file system.
Also consider restart the Netbeans or even Windows.

Comment: Seems after a bit of messing about, I managed to get it working.  

I think my Netbeans was just a bit confused over where to look to find the necessary files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MacOS, even after install Java 7 the default SDK is still Java 6, despite the FX can be activated. Simply add JDK7 and it should fix the problem.